# Get Work items from build Visual Studio Online API

Tags: api, azure-devops

I'm using Visual Studio Online API to get all the work items from an specific build. The problem is that the build numbers I have - because I customize them - have a dot inside the value, for example 112321.3, so it seems that it does not reconize that in the query. 
My query es the following:
https://xxxx.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/xxxSoft/_apis/build/builds/20161101.2/workitems?api-version=2.0
but it returns page not found eventhough the build exits.
Any clue?
Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/workitems?api-version={version}
```

It is based on the buildId to get workitems per build, instead of build number.

[image]

**So Steps for your requirement:**

1. Based on the build number to get corresponding build

   https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version={version}[&definitions={string}][&queues={string}][&buildNumber={string}][&type={string}][&minFinishTime={DateTime}][&maxFinishTime={DateTime}][&requestedFor={string}][&reasonFilter={string}][&statusFilter={string}][&tagFilters={string}][&propertyFilters={string}][&$top={int}][&continuationToken={string}]

For example:

```
https://XXX.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/Scrum2015/_apis/build/builds?buildNumber=20161117.17&api-version=2.0
```

2. Get workitems per build id.